# why React spend some idle time before triggering API-fetching in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have a loading related issue with a page I make with React.
I want to show data right after a user access to the routed page. However there is a delay displaying it, even though the data is not that heavy.

As I look into Performance tab in chrome devtoos, I found something working weirdly.

[image: captured image]

Let me explain how my code works with the above picture.

When I clicked a button which routes user to a new `page component`, the "scripting", "rendering" and "painting" start working. Theses processes are displayed in the first red box I marked. The network process in the first redbox is about favicon.ico, so it is negligible.

But the thing is, I intended to fetch data using `useEffect` with no dependencies as I wrote the code below,  right after paint basic stuff in the component .

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDataFromCertainApi());
  }, []);
```

But as you can see in the picture, the network process is triggered about 2.5s later. This is shown in the second redbox in the picture.

I have no idea what my application is doing for that long time without processing anything. Is that related to useEffect or others in React application?

Comment: could you show more screenshots about the network and so on?

Comment: Sure! What would be needed to help you to understand my problem more?